# png() function in R fail to create png file with dimension larger than 3000x3000px

Tags: r, png, ggplot2

I have trying to generate some map using `ggplot` and `sp`, I have a basemap with the original size of `3000+ x 3000+` pixels, I also have some with `2000+ x 2000+` pixels. Interestingly, until now I still cannot create the `3000+ x 3000+` pixel png files, as R gives me the following error:

```
Error in png(chart.filename, width = basemap.xlength, height = basemap.ylength,  : 
  unable to start png() device
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In png(chart.filename, width = basemap.xlength, height = basemap.ylength,  :
  Unable to allocate bitmap
2: In png(chart.filename, width = basemap.xlength, height = basemap.ylength,  :
  opening device failed
```

Is that a limitation to R? Can how I get through it? Thanks.

I am using Win7 with R 2.15.0.

Comment: What operating system is this and can you reproduce the error with reproducible code?

Comment: It's not an intrinsic R limitation: `x <- runif(10000); y <- runif(10000); png("tmp.png",5000,5000); plot(x,y); dev.off()` works fine on my system (Ubuntu 10.04, 32-bit, R-devel). The created file is 640K.

Comment: Works for me too on Win7 / R 2.15.0. I have 8 GB of memory...

Answer (score 5):

`Unable to allocate bitmap` suggest you have memory problems, so I would experiment with smaller allocations, provide details about your system and some reproducible code.

What you describe works for me - though I wouldn't advise actually running this since it creates a pretty wasteful file:

```
png("a.png", width = 3000, height = 3000)
image(matrix(rnorm(3000*3000), 3000), useRaster = TRUE)
dev.off()
```